# How to make this selection?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with column name `LIST_CODE` where data like this A101,A102,B101.

How can I find all the data where `LIST_CODE` equal **A102** OR **B101**

I try bellow sql but it returns **0**

```
SELECT count(*) FROM details_user WHERE list_code IN ('A102','C101')
```

Comment: The value of the `list_code` field is the string `"A101,A102,B101"` complete with commas and all?

Comment: It should work..!! so there may be something wrong with the data actually, make sure it doesn't contain space before or after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that list_code can contain 'A101, A102,B101' in one row then

```
select * from details_user
where list_code like'%A102%' 
or list_code like '%B101%'
```

But this would be a bad database design.

if list_code can contain

```
A101
A102
B101
```

(one value per row)

Then your code is correct, and it's just mean that you have no row with A102 or C101.

Answer (score 0):

As there's a limit on the query length, you may also want to consider constructing a regular expression like `SELECT count(*) FROM details_user RLIKE list_code RLIKE "A102|B100".

In any case, that's not a good schema design.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, when you have data that should be in rows, place it in rows. No amount of code is replacement for a good initial design.

That said, you can use the xml function in sql server 2005 and above to transform data that is packed into a single row into a somewhat more manageable situation. You can do something like:

```
select du.ID, Code.value('.','nvarchar(100)') as Code
from (select ID, 
        cast(('<c>'+replace(list_Code,',' ,'</c><c>')+'</c>') as xml) as xml
      from details_user) du
cross apply du.xml.nodes('c') as T(Code)
```

This first transforms the string from a `'A101, A102'` format into a XML-like format,
 `'<c>A101</c><c>A102</c>'`.

Then the transformed value is fed into the [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) function that separates the codes into a table, and from that table, the value of the code is extracted using the [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) method.

You can play with this approach on this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59f29/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid the 'IN' operator only works on discrete sets and not on varchars like you're suggesting.

So you'd have to use a regular OR statement or use a different definition of your value set.

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM details_user WHERE list_code = 'A102' OR list_code ='C101'
```